# @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)

Tags: java, spring, annotations

if some one can explain what this annotation do and when exactly we use it :

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: Propagation.REQUIRED is the default propagation mode of Transaction, so you don't need to explicitly set it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When the propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, a logical transaction scope is created for each method upon which the setting is applied. Each such logical transaction scope can determine rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope being logically independent from the inner transaction scope. Of course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all these scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction. So a rollback-only marker set in the inner transaction scope does affect the outer transaction's chance to actually commit (as you would expect it to).

[image]

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Answer (score 179):

If you need a laymans explanation of the use beyond that provided in the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation)

Consider this code...

```
class Service {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomething() {
        // access a database using a DAO
    }
}
```

When doSomething() is called it knows it has to start a Transaction on the database before executing. If the caller of this method has already started a Transaction then this method will use that same *physical* Transaction on the current database connection.

This `@Transactional` annotation provides a means of telling your code when it executes that it *must* have a Transaction. It will not run without one, so you can make this assumption in your code that you wont be left with incomplete data in your database, or have to clean something up if an exception occurs.

Transaction management is a fairly complicated subject so hopefully this simplified answer is helpful

Comment: If anyone is interested, I posted [a similar layman's answer comparing PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, PROPAGATION_NESTED, PROPAGATION_REQUIRED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076718/spring-propagation-examples-in-laymans-terms/25083505#25083505)

Comment: if it's using proxy based configuration to declare and access to DAO layer, the method into DAO class must be annotated with @Transactional too.

Comment: If you have added `@Transactional` to your service layer, there is no further requirement to also add `@Transactional` to the DAO methods being called within that transaction.

Comment: if `doSomething()` invokes a another nested method without any @transactional will this same transaction will apply to that invoking method as well?

Comment: Yes, so long as the same Thread is being used to execute a nested method (i.e. you don't create a new Thread explicitly). This is because Spring transactions are bound to the current Thread using ThreadLocal variables

Answer (score 16):

In Spring applications, if you enable annotation based transaction support using `<tx:annotation-driven/>` and annotate any class/method with **@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)** then Spring framework will start a transaction and executes the method and commits the transaction. If any RuntimeException occurred  then the transaction will be rolled back.

Actually propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED is default propagation level, you don't need to explicitly mentioned it.

For further info : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Answer (score 5):

To understand the various transactional settings and behaviours adopted for Transaction management, such as `REQUIRED`, `ISOLATION` etc. you'll have to understand the basics of transaction management itself.

Read [Trasaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html) for more on explanation.