# spring transactional nested open session?

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, transactional, hibernate-session

If a method of service is marked as `@Transactional` with propagation nested, and inside it there are many calls to other `@Transactional` methods, each one of these methods will use its own session? It should represent many connections to db for just one method call no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` is better option for your purpose. From its javadoc:

***Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists***.

[Refer this link for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear but it's just curiosity, I always use default propagation of Spring, so I always have only on transaction (the outer one). But the q

Comment: yes so using propagation you can give multiple recursive calls to the transaction you no need to worry for that :)

Comment: yes but my question was about sessions, what about this recursive calls getting sessions? it means that calling one method it could use N connections to db?

Comment: No only one conection at a time

Comment: It's explained in some place? Im unable to find it :S

Comment: refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740021/transactionalpropagation-propagation-required